# Will filters be invoked for AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, jsf, servlet-filters

I was reading through Filter concepts and have a doubt if filters will be invoked for AJAX requests in JSF application.

Filter mapping is as below

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ModuleSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.The filter will be invoked as long as the submits from your JSF views are to the URL matching the filter's `url-pattern`. In your case if the submit is for any "`/protected/anything`"

With JSF1.2, all your command actions (commandbutton/commandlinks) will be forced to POST submit the form data to the same view.

Say your current view is `/protected/firstview.jsf` , then all your `<h:commandButton /> , <h:commandLink />, <a4j:commandButton /> <a4j:commandLink /> , <a4j:support action="" />` will be submitting a POST reqest to the same view `/protected/firstview.jsf`. So all therequests will have to go through the filter.